# Mutually commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A_{1},..., A_{m}$ be $n \times n$ matrices with entries in a field $K$ such that $A_{i}A_{j} = A_{j}A_{i}$ for all $ 1 \leq i, j \leq n$ and the product $A_{1}A_{2} ... A_{m} = 0$ is the zero matrix. Prove that there are $h \leq n$ distinct indices $i_{1}, ..., i_{h}$ such that $A_{i_{1}} ... A_{i_{h}} = 0$.

I showed, by inducting on $m$, that the matrices in question have a set of common eigenvectors, say $B$ and not necessarily same eigenvalues. Then on $B$, we see that some eigenvalues have to be zeros. From here, I can use a hint.

Someone mentioned a hint: reduce the rank to zero, which did not get me very far [sorry to you, I posted this problem in math overflow, which was not appropriate for a mere linear algebra qual prep problems and so I moved it here].

Comment: Were you able to show that there is a basis of common eigenvectors or only that there are some common eigenvectors?

Comment: Series of hints. Can you do the problem if the matrices $A_j$ are all diagonal matrices? Then, can you do the problem if the matrices are all diagonalizable? Switching gears, can you do the problem if $A_1=\dots=A_m$? Combining the last two variants should allow you to do the whole problem, with the help of say Jordan normal forms.

Comment: Michael Albanese, commutativity is not enough to claim the existence of a basis of simultaneous eigenvectors.

Comment: Greg, commutativity of the matrices together with assuming that each one of the $A_{j}$ is diagonalizable would imply there is a basis of simultaneous eigenvectors (inductive argument). Your suggestion is fine exception one has to move upstairs to work in the algebraic closure of K. If nothing much cleaner comes up, I can live with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following (not quite my original idea) actually seems to work better:

Keep track of the null spaces $N(A_k\cdots A_1)$ of segments of the product. As long as $N(A_k\cdots A_1)\not= N(A_{k-1}\cdots A_1)$, this null space grows by at least one dimension for each factor, so will be the whole space after $n$ steps, as desired.

On the other hand, if $N(A_k\cdots A_1)=N(A_{k-1}\cdots A_1)$, then removing $A_k$ will not increase the rank of the whole product because this part can go on the left and thus
$$
A_k\cdots A_1 P \quad\textrm{and}\quad A_{k-1}\cdots A_1 P
$$
($P$ contains the remaining $A$'s) annihilate the same vectors. So if we remove along the way the $A_k$'s where the null space stabilizes, then the procedure described in the first paragraph will lead to a product with at most $n$ factors that is still zero.